# Unable to update war in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a war in tomcat server in aws Beanstalk.

When I am updating the war by upload and deploy in aws beanstalk, it'still running the previous version of war.

can anyone tell me, why it's not updating the war even though I am able to upload.

Answer (score 1):

That could happen if a new web api causes errors and cannot run, then AWS may use old version from backup. (and this will be your previos version). Did you test your new version locally?